# accessing dynamically allocated variable in c++

Tags: c++

how can I instantiate a class object statistically from main having a no argument constructor which initializes one of its attributes to an int value. this attribute is a pointer in c++. I tried dereferencing the variable int* pages to access  the value it is pointing but this did not work in  main()

```
class Book {
private:
    int *pages;
public:
    void setPages(int num) {
        pages = num;
    }
    int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }
};

int main() {
    Book b1;
    int* pages;
    *pages = 500;
    b1.setPages(500);
    cout      << "number of pages are = " << b1.getPages << endl;
}
```

I suppose what I intend to achieve is dynamically allocate memory for the int inside the no argument constructor.

Comment: Could you please format your code properly. This way it's pretty hard to read.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory?  For a single `int`, declare `int`.  For more than one `int`, use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: By the way, I recommend using `unsigned int` for better safety, since books can't have a negative number of pages.  The `unsigned` allows the compiler to perform checking for a negative page count (during compilation).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
pages = num;
```

should be

```
pages = &num;
```

You should assign the memory address of the `num` to `pages` using `&` (address of operator), not the variable itself.

and
 `b1.getPages` should be corrected as `b1.getPages()`.

I don't know why you declared this pointer since you haven't used it in your code.
`int* pages;`

But if you are going to use it you can do it this way

```
int* pages;
*pages = 500; 
b1.setPages(*pages);
```

OR

```
int pages;
pages = 500; 
b1.setPages(pages);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do

```
void setPages(int num) {
    *pages = num;
}
```

and

```
int getPages() {
    return *pages;
}
```

Otherwise, the code won't compile.

Initially, you were trying

```
pages = num;
```

and `pages` is an int pointer and `num` is an int, so this won't work.

And then, you were trying

```
int getPages() {
    return pages;
}
```

the function has the return type int, but it tries to return a pointer.

Also, change the function call to

```
cout << "number of pages are = " << b1.getPages() << endl;
                                                ^ you are missing these
```

The next problem with you code is in your `main()`

```
int* pages;
*pages = 500;
```

`pages` is not pointing to any address, and you get a SEGFAULT here.

So, you can modify your code to something like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Book 
  {
    private:
      int *pages;
    public:
      void setPages(int num) 
        {
          pages = new int;
          *pages = num;
        }    
      int getPages() 
        {
          return *pages;
        }
      void d()
        {
          delete pages;
        }
  };
int main() 
  {
    Book b1;
    int* pages = new int;
    *pages = 500;
    b1.setPages(500);
    cout << "number of pages are = " << b1.getPages() << endl;
    delete pages;
    b1.d();
  }
```

This may not be the most efficient, but try it out.

Comment: And if you were to call `setPages` more than once, you have a memory leak.  I don't think you can make lemonade out of this lemon of code that the OP posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , I agree with you over there. Since there are no variables that can be used in the original code, I decided to use DP. But this code is purely for this question. It's like you said, if you call `setpages()` twice, then there will be a memory leak.